# AWS SSH connect from OSX keep asking for password for SSH Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, osx-mavericks, ssh-keys

As per Ben's answer, I created a key pair, downloaded the private key into ~/.ssh  , changed the permissions to 600 and tried to ssh the instance ... but got unauthorized erro :

```
    $ ssh -v -i  ~/.ssh/aws-erwin16.pem jack@ec2-nn-nn-nnn-nnn.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jack/.ssh/config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to ec2-nn-nn-nnn-nnn.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.69.113.179] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/jack/.ssh/aws-erwin16.pem type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/jack/.ssh/aws-erwin16.pem-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: RSA 85:e4:69:56:21:4d:32:1c:e9:5c:83:a5:cc:28:03:39
    debug1: Host 'ec2-nn-nn-nnn-nnn.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/jack/.ssh/known_hosts:22
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/jack/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jack/.ssh/aws-erwin16.pem
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).
```

if I change the user name for ubuntu , and it runs fine... get connecte d..;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused the [X.509 Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#X509Credentials) with the [Amazon EC2 Keypairs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#EC2KeyPairs). EC2 Keypairs are used to log in to EC2 instances.

In the EC2 console, find the keypairs section on the left, generate a keypair, and save the private key locally to your disk. OpenSSH searches the `~/.ssh` directory by default. Run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/<filename>` to set the correct permissions. You can then use that key to access your instance via SSH.

Comment: updated my question .. ( and badly deleted the first post..)  whern a create a key pair within AWS , the private key is automatically downloaded ... but seems not going well in using it